# Random numbers in java does not work properly

Tags: java, random

I want to create a lottery program that creates four random numbers, each between 0 and 9 (inclusive). This program asks user to guess four numbers and compares each user guesses to four random numbers and displays the won message as:

```
No matches  0 points
Any one digit matching  5 points
Any two digits matching 100 points
Any three digits matching   2,000 points
All four digits matching    1,000,000 points
```

My program runs  but it has some logic errors.  For example,the output should be:

```
Random numbers:2 3 3 4
Guess numbers: 1 2 5 7-->1 matching digit
Guess numbers: 3 5 7 3-->2 matching digits
Guess numbers: 3 3 3 1-->2 matching digits
Guess numbers: 3 3 3 3-->2 matching digits
```

```java
public class Lottery
{           
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final  int LIMIT=10; 
        int totalCount=0;
        int totalPoint;
        Random random=new Random(); //creating object of random class       
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);//creating object of scanner class     
        //declaring two arrays
        int[] guessNumber= new int[4];
        int[] randomNumber=new int[4];       

 for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {            

    randomNumber[i]=random.nextInt(LIMIT);//returns value between 0 to 9(inclusive)     
   }     

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
    System.out.println("Enter your first guess number from 0 to 9:");
    guessNumber[i]=input.nextInt(); 
    } 



for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
   {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
      {

        if (randomNumber[i] == guessNumber[j])
           {
        ++totalCount; 
        break; 
        }
       }
   }        

   if(totalCount == 1)
     {
        totalPoint=5;
      }
   else if(totalCount == 2)
     {
        totalPoint=100;
      }
   else if(totalCount == 3)
      {
        totalPoint=2000;
      }
    else if(totalCount == 4)
       {
        totalPoint=100000;
       }    
    else
       {
       totalPoint=0;
       }


//dispalying points 
    System.out.println("You have earned " +totalPoint+ "points!!");
            }
      }
```

Comment: How is it 'not working properly?'

Comment: Try to format properly your code (braces, intenting), it makes it so much easy to read it.

Comment: there is an online code formatter

Comment: What is working and what isn't working?  What are the actual results and what are the expected results?  Is the problem simply that your actual results don't match your expected results, or is there a crash?  Or does it simply fail to compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like the problem is that once you've matched a particular digit, you ought to be removing it from circulation so that multiple guesses of the same value don't count as matches. One solution is to use an ArrayList for the `randomNumber`'s and remove them when there's a match.  If you replace what's between your `// declaring two arrays` comment and your `totalPoint` assignment with the following it seems to do what you requested in terms of your example.

```
int guess;
ArrayList<Integer> randomNumber = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   randomNumber.add(random.nextInt(LIMIT));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   System.out.print("Enter your guess number from 0 to 9: ");
   guess = input.nextInt();
   for (int j = 0; j < randomNumber.size(); ++j) {
      if (randomNumber.get(j) == guess) {
         ++totalCount;
         randomNumber.remove(j);
         break;
      }
   }
}
input.close();
```

Note that I've chosen to process each guess as it's read rather than store them in an array and process them later.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your overall logic is fine.
If I understand correctly, you just want a different output.
Use something like this for your output.

```
String guessNumbers = "";
String randomNumbers = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    randomNumbers += randomNumber[i]+" ";
    guessNumbers += guessNumber[i]+" ";
}
System.out.println("Random numbers: "+randomNumbers);
System.out.println("Guess numbers: "+guessNumbers+" --> # of matching digits "+totalCount);
System.out.println("You have earned " +totalPoint+ " points!!");
```

This is what it now prints:

```
Random numbers: 2 9 7 4 
Guess numbers: 7 4 5 2  --> # of matching digits 3
You have earned 2000 points!!
```